# Do any fish have to hold their urine in deep water?

Tags: ichthyology

I know this is going to sound really weird! But I was confronted with this claim and the person strongly had faith in it! I said **faith** since he couldn't provide any evidence.

- Is there any kind of fish that is forced to hold his urine when in deep water ?
- If yes, is there any relationship between the case with fish's scale ?
- Does that make the fish's meat not proper (poisonous) to eat ?

I don't know what depth would be proper to define here but I guess the matter to be rare and not so important to define.

Comment: Is there any rational for which a fish would be forced to hold its urine in deep water?

Answer (score 5):

In a salty environment there is the risk of loosing water by osmosis.
There are different strategies to prevent this.
One of them is to **hold the salts of the urine** (not the urine itself) by reuptaking them from the kidney.
The resulting high internal salt concentration prevents the water loss.

This strategy is used by **Sharks and rays/ skates**, they take up urea and [TMAO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trimethylamine_N-oxide) from the kidneys. Those metabolites are highly concentrated in their blood, which makes them **unhealthy to eat**, when fresh. However, after fermenting they are edible: **[Hakarl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%A1karl)** is an icelandic dish of fermented shark. The linked Wikipedia-Article gives more details about the topic.

I guess your friend was referring to this phenomenon, but his memory was a bit imprecise.

Answer (score 0):

Fishes have urinary bladder too. It would be hard to hide from predators with an urine trail pointing towards you. I don't think this is size dependent.

[image]
 - [ref](http://www.easynotecards.com/notecard_set/8097)

Urine is usually not that dangerous and we remove inner organs, like urinary bladder by the preparation of the meat, so this is not a problem.